# How to apply the type erasure technique to existing types?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, types, polymorphism

As we know, if we are designing a type system from scratch, then we can use the type erasure technique to implement polymorphism. However, how should we apply the type erasure technique to existing types like the following case?

```
struct A
{
    int f()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct B
{
    int f() 
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

template<class TypeForOtherUse> // Don't put A or B here
struct C
{
    C(A a)
    : obj_of_A_or_B(a)
    {}

    C(B b)
    : obj_of_A_or_B(b)
    {}

    int g()
    {
        return obj_of_A_or_B.f();
    }

    /* ??? What should be put here ??? */ obj_of_A_or_B;
};
```

Comment: [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)?

Comment: Designing a type system means changing the programming language. You do not seem to be doing that. So there is no difference between new types and existing types. In this case `obj_of_A_or_B` should be of type `Base *` which has a `virtual int foo()`. Then you have a `template<class T> class Derived <A> : Base` and the same for `<B>` that override the `virtual foo`. Same as any type erasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) has a full on type erasure library that lets you pick what you erase.

However, a simple case like the above can be done as follows:

```
// The interface detailing what we support.  Move is always supported.
// only need clone if we want to copy:
struct IImpl {
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IImpl> clone() const = 0;
  virtual int f() = 0;
  virtual ~IImpl() {}
};

// The pImpl<T> class writes custom code to type erase a type T.
// you can specialize it for extreme cases: ie, suppose for some type X
// you want f() to invoke g() -- then you can specialize Impl to do that.
// (that is a bit of a toy example, and a bad one, but imagine std::function
// specialized for method pointers such that `this` is turned into the first
// argument)
template<class T>
struct Impl:IImpl {
  T t;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IImpl> clone() const override {
    return std::unique_ptr<IImpl>( new Impl(t) );
  }
  virtual int f() const override {
    return t.f();
  }
  virtual ~Impl() {}
  template<typename...Us>
  explicit Impl( Us&&... us ): t(std::forward<Us>(us)...) {}
  // copy is handled by clone.  move is handled by unique_ptr:
  Impl( Impl const& ) = delete;
  Impl& operator=( Impl const& ) = delete;
};

// the value-semantics class that type-erases:
struct TypeErased {
  std::unique_ptr<IImpl> pImpl; // where the work is mostly done
  int f() { return pImpl->f(); } // forward to where the work is mostly done
  template<typename T, typename... Us> // pass T explicitly, allow construction from other types
  void emplace( Us&&... us ) { pImpl.reset( new Impl<T>(std::forward<Us>(us)...) ); }
  template<typename T> // like std::function, sucks in similar ways
  explicit TypeErased( T&& t ): pImpl( new Impl<typename std::decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(t)) {};
  TypeErased(TypeErased&&) = default;
  TypeErased(TypeErased const&o): pImpl( o.pImpl?o.pImpl->clone():nullptr ) {}
  TypeErased(TypeErased const&&o):TypeErased(o) {} // delegate to const&, no need to cast here
  TypeErased(TypeErased&o):TypeErased( const_cast<TypeErased const&>(o) {} // delegate to const&

  TypeErased& operator=(TypeErased&&) = default; // moving the unique_ptr does the right thing
  TypeErased& operator=(TypeErased const&o) { // copy-swap idiom
    TypeErased tmp(o);
    this->swap(tmp);
    return *this;
  }
  void swap( TypeErased& o ) {
    std::swap( pImpl, o.pImpl );
  }
};

// You can make this a template on other types, but I'll omit it, as it just fuzzies things up:
struct C {
  C(A a): erased(a) {}
  C(B b): erased(b) {}
  int g() {
    return erased.f();
  }
  TypeErased erased;
};
```

not compiled, but I read it over again and got rid of most of the typos.